# wp_enqueue_media() Will not load JS on the theme

Tags: uploads, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, media-library

I've added wp_enqueue_media() to a specific page (before including the header) on my custom theme but it flat out will not any of the JS on the page.

I've already done the basic troubleshooting:

1. Deactivated all plugins (no go)
2. changed themes to twenty sixteen, this time leaving all the plugins activated, and added wp_enqueue_media() function to the page.php template (that works)
3. moved the function to the wp_head (still doesnt work)
4. commented out everything from my functions file (thus stopping any of my JS,styles, and hooks from being loaded - but this also doesn't work)
5. Cleaned the DB and did a fresh install (doesn't work)

so steps 1 and 2 rules out plugin conflicts, and 4 should rule out something in my functions file. I dont know where to go from here.

note - 
In my functions file, I was unregistering jquery to use a different version. When I did that, nothing loaded with the wp_enqueue_media function. But when I commented out that line I was able to get a few more scripts:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.3
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0
plupload.full.min.js?ver=2.1.8
```

Comment: Why [`wp_enqueue_media()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_media/)? This is only meant to load media JS API scripts, styles and markup. What JavaScript files are we talking about? Why are you not using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)?

Comment: I want to get the media library (including media uploading) and the wp_enqueue_media() function should enqueue all the js files needed

Comment: Yes, it should load everything related to media upload (_including JS, HTML and CSS_). Im not sure how many files it should load.. How do you know that it doesn't load all required files? Did you test media upload? From documents: `This function should be called from the 'admin_enqueue_scripts' action hook, or later.` Make sure that all requirements are met, [here's](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_media) more information about it.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. You put me in the right direction. See answer below

Answer (score 3):

I had 2 things wrong:

1. I unregistered wordpress's jquery without properly registering my own (I concatenated my scripts )
2. I didnt have wp_footer() in my theme. the wp_enqueue_media() function loads the scripts to the footer.